# CakePHP 3: search form with get method and find condition, how to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an HTML form with the GET method, and five text input field, which should help to filter the data. When users fill one or more fields, these data are shown as url query.

My question is how to safely use the this query data without the possibility of SQL injection?

**EDIT**
Of course, is a simple filtering of user data, by name, location, etc., not fulltext search.

```
'first_name LIKE' => '%'.$this->request->query('first_name').'%'
```

Where is in the documentation explained bind method, like ?

`->bind(':name', $this->request->query('name'))`

Comment: The risk is to manually build the SQL condition and pass the parameters inside quotes. Please specify how you want your search to work (e.g using `=`, `LIKE`, full text search, etc.)

Comment: Search using `LIKE` .

Comment: The key/value array syntax already protects against that, the value part will be prepared with respect to the column type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities, you can use *query placeholders*.

Your code should look something similar to

```
$query = $this->Users->find()
    ->where([
        'first_name LIKE' => '%:name%'
    ])
    ->bind(':name', $this->request->query('first_name'));
```

More information in:

- [Binding Values](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#binding-values) in *Cookbook 3.x: Database Access & ORM*
- [`Query::bind()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_bind)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Search Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/3.0/docs/Tutorials/Quick-Start.md)

Its just very simple, write this in controller

```
public $components = array(
    'Search.Prg'
);

public function index() {
    $this->Prg->commonProcess();
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users->find('searchable',
    $this->Prg->parsedParams())));
}
```

And this one in Model

```
public $filterArgs = array(
    'first_name' => array(
        'type' => 'like',
        'field' => 'first_name'
    )
);

public function initialize(array $config = []) {
    $this->addBehavior('Search.Searchable');
}
```

and you are done.

For more examples, visit [here](https://github.com/CakeDC/search/blob/3.0/docs/Documentation/Examples.md)